# PHP using " character inside string argument

Tags: php

I am trying to call `str_replace` method in `PHP`.

I wanna replace `\"` with `"` but I am having issues doing that. I think `PHP` interprets `"` wrong. Is there a chance to avoid that.

```
$data = str_replace('\"','"',trim(ob_get_contents()));
```

**Edit:**

This is a extract of the content I am editing:

```
<div class=\"container-fluid\">
```

I would like to get

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

**Edit 2:**

I tested removing `\n`. Interesting it only worked when using `""` not `''`

```
$data = str_replace("\n","",$test_str); // working
$data = str_replace("\n","",$test_str); // NOT working
```

Comment: Did you left the `"` in the replacement string on purpose?

Comment: Try `stripslashes` function.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov You are right, thanks. Forgot ". I wanna replace it to "

Comment: @VinayPatil Will read about it, thanks

Comment: What is happening? Is there some error or just nothing happens?

Comment: @davidev http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c55f8ca49ee96f6f260298024e9d2bc291b3ad80

Comment: @MartinDimitrov No error, it just not replacing it

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Thank you sir for the example. Working indeed. In my code not, I will figure out

Comment: Add expected output and actual output that you are getting in the question.

Comment: Can you give us `var_dump(trim(ob_get_contents()))`?

Comment: Thanks all for the great help. You are right, the function is working now with your help. My problem was that I put it into an array afterwards, where the \" was added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Option 1:**

```
$str = '<div class=\"container-fluid\">';
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Demo [link](https://3v4l.org/L07YO)

**Option 2:**

```
$str = '<div class=\"container-fluid\">';
echo str_replace("\\", "", $str);
```

Demo [link](https://3v4l.org/asO22)

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working for me but only if I echo it. If I reference it to a new variable, it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: If the string even in your question is a part of the content then it should work. What are you getting as output same content as input?

Comment: You are right. I echo it, and it worked. Saving it on a new variable aswell. I saved it afterwards in an array and then output the array. As the array uses "" it created the \" again

Comment: If you are saving that `HTML` output in an array then it will be converted to a string again which will result PHP will add slashes again to a string. My suggestion is to replace the slashes at the time of displaying HTML on page.

Comment: @VinayPatil Yeah that's what I am doing. I would like to get the output directly ready. The one getting the output shouldn't need to parse or edit it anymore. Any chance to add this to an array without the escape \?

Comment: Can you update the array code also in the question? as per your last comment question in incomplete to provide the desired output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202708/discussion-between-davidev-and-vinay-patil).

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '<div class=\"container-fluid\">';
$data = str_replace('\"', '"', trim($str));
var_dump($data); // <div class="container-fluid">
```

In PHP a string can be defined by single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`.
The difference between them is that double quotes are strings parsing mode, which means, they can parse variables and special chars inside them. While using single quotes they treat them as a pure string as they come.
You can read more about them in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/3454593